# Does Informatica Web Services Hub v9 support MTOM?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, informatica-powercenter

Whilst this isn't directly a programming question, the answer **will** highly influence the solution adopted.

I am looking at developing a Java client to transfer data (files) into Informatica Powercentre Web Services Hub (WSH).  Best practice suggests to use MTOM for large files being sent via SOAP requests.

I'm assuming support for consuming MTOM attachments is vendor specific, one can't assume it works out of the box ?

If anyone can confirm whether Power Center 9.x supports this, it'd be muchly appreciated. I've spent a lot of time on the Informatica Communities and reading documents but it is rather opaque to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RTFM**

It appears that MTOM is not supported. From PowerCenter WebServices Provider Guide v 9.0.1 page 80 "WSDL Attachments".

> The attachment must be a text file such as an XML document. You cannot attach binary documents... To use a binary file as a source, convert the file into hexbinary or base64binary before you pass it to the web service source. A hexbinary or base64binary files is treated as a text file.